# Float array to double array and back, quickly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sse

I need to convert large arrays of `float` in memory to arrays of `double` and back. Are there any SSE compiler intrinsics in Visual C++ 15 update 3 that would help?

EDIT: it's a conversion between two wire formats, so #define won't help. A data structure is stored as floats, but a third party processing library expects an array of double.

Comment: `#define double float` or vice-versa

Comment: There's no way to save you from casting every single value.

Comment: Are you looking to get the slight possible loss when converting back?  Otherwise, just convert one way and keep the original to save the convert back.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the float arrays to double and then back again? What does this accomplish?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: SSE has many instructions named `CVT*`.  It may be that none go between these exact datatypes, but in the wider sense looking for an SSE instruction to parallelize casting is a reasonable thing.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's true but there could be a techniques that can add speed to the process for ex. using  ALU instead FPU.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - the conversions in both directions can be done without casting.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm eager to read the answer now.

Comment: How about writing a naive loop and allowing the compiler to figure out the vectorisation?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I think you missed my point. float to double does not require **casting**, nor does double to float; both can be done by implicit conversions.

Comment: @PeteBecker For whole arrays as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use SSE for this:

`float` -> `double`: [`_mm_cvtps_pd`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_cvtps_pd&expand=1679)

`double` -> `float`: [`_mm_cvtpd_ps`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_cvtpd_ps&expand=1679)

Try a simple scalar loop first though as (a) the compiler may vectorize for you anyway and (b) you may well be memory-bound, so SIMD optimisation may not help much.

Comment: That's useful, but it works with 128-bit XMM registers, doesn't it? That is, only two values per command. Is there a flavor of those instructions that would employ YMM instead and handle 4 values?

Comment: Yes of course, see the AVX equivalents, [_mm256_cvtps_pd](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_cvtps_pd&expand=1680,1680) and [_mm256_cvtpd_ps](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_cvtpd_ps&expand=1680,1680,1621), although note that these may not give you any significant improvement over the SSE versions, for the reasons noted above.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an actual answer to your question but just a example how to make only ALU work on conversion. You can parallel it with FPU cast to get more speed if you implement it properly. This solution should be 100% IEEE compatible.

Update: I make this slower and more readable but IEEE compatible as intel implement it in 3rd generation of i7 (to the point where even NAN conversion is binary equale)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

#include <math.h>

void toDouble(float *inData, double *outData, int count)
{
    if (count % 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Error count must be divided by 2" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    unsigned long long *pfData = (unsigned long long *)(inData);
    unsigned long long *pdData = (unsigned long long *)(outData);

    unsigned long long *pfDataEnd = pfData + count / 2;

    for (int i = 0; pfData<pfDataEnd; pfData++, pdData++, i += 2)
    {
        unsigned long long cl;

        unsigned long long S1 = (*pfData & 0x80000000ull) << 32;
        unsigned long long fE1 = (*pfData & 0x7F800000ull) << 32;
        unsigned long long F1 = (*pfData & 0x007FFFFFull) << 29;

        for (cl = 0; !fE1 && F1 && !(F1 & 0x7FF0000000000000ull); cl++)
            F1 <<= 1;
        if (cl > 0)
            cl--;

        unsigned long long dE1 = (fE1 == 0x7F80000000000000ull) ? 0x7FF0000000000000 : ((fE1 | F1) ? (fE1 >> 3) + 0x3800000000000000ull - cl * 0x0010000000000000ull : 0ull);

        F1 &= 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFull;

        *pdData = S1 | dE1 | F1;

        pdData++;

        unsigned long long S2 = *pfData & 0x8000000000000000ull;
        unsigned long long fE2 = (*pfData & 0x7F80000000000000ull);
        unsigned long long F2 = (*pfData & 0x007FFFFF00000000ull) >> 3;

        for (cl = 0; !fE2 && F2 && !(F2 & 0x7FF0000000000000ull); cl++)
            F2 <<= 1;
        if (cl > 0)
            cl--;

        unsigned long long dE2 = (fE2==0x7F80000000000000ull) ? 0x7FF0000000000000 : ( (fE2 | F2) ? (fE2 >> 3) + 0x3800000000000000ull - cl * 0x0010000000000000ull : 0ull);

        F2 &= 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFull;

        *pdData = S2 | dE2 | F2;

        if (i == 126)
            continue;
    }
}

void toFloat(double *inData, float *outData, int count)
{
    if (count % 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Error count must be divided by 2" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    unsigned long long *pdData = (unsigned long long *)(inData);
    unsigned long long *pfData = (unsigned long long *)(outData);

    unsigned long long *pfDataEnd = pfData + count / 2;

    for (int i=0; pfData<pfDataEnd; pfData++, pdData+=2,i+=2)
    {
        unsigned long long S1 = (*pdData & 0x8000000000000000ull);
        unsigned long long dE1 = (*pdData & 0x7FF0000000000000ull);
        unsigned long long fE1 = (dE1 <= 0x3800000000000000ull) ? 0ull : ((dE1 >= 0x4800000000000000ull) ? 0x0FF0000000000000ull : (dE1 - 0x3800000000000000ull));
        unsigned long long F1 = (dE1 <= 0x3800000000000000ull) ? ((dE1 < 0x3600000000000000ull) ? 0ull : ((*pdData & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFull | 0x0010000000000000ull) >> ((0x3800000000000000ull - dE1 >> 52) + 1))) : ((dE1 >= 0x47F0000000000000ull) ? (((dE1 == 0x7FF0000000000000ull) && (*pdData & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFull)) ? 0x0008000000000000ull : 0ull) : (*pdData & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFull));
        F1 += (((F1 & 0x0000000010000000ull) && ((F1 & 0x0000000020000000ull) || (F1 & 0x000000000FFFFFFFull))) ? 0x0000000020000000ull : 0ull); //rounding
        fE1 += F1 & 0x7FF0000000000000ull;
        F1 &= 0x000FFFFFE0000000ull;

        unsigned long long S2 = (*(pdData+1) & 0x8000000000000000ull);
        unsigned long long dE2 = (*(pdData+1) & 0x7FF0000000000000ull);
        unsigned long long fE2 =  ( dE2 <= 0x3800000000000000ull) ? 0ull : ((dE2 >= 0x4800000000000000ull) ? 0x0FF0000000000000ull : (dE2 - 0x3800000000000000ull));
        unsigned long long F2 = (dE2 <= 0x3800000000000000ull) ? ((dE2 < 0x3600000000000000ull) ? 0ull : ((*(pdData + 1) & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFull | 0x0010000000000000ull) >> ((0x3800000000000000ull - dE2 >> 52) + 1))) : ((dE2 >= 0x47F0000000000000ull) ? (((dE2 == 0x7FF0000000000000ull) && (*(pdData+1) & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFull)) ? 0x0008000000000000ull : 0ull) : (*(pdData + 1) & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFull));

        F2 += (((F2 & 0x0000000010000000ull) && ((F2 & 0x0000000020000000ull) || (F2 & 0x000000000FFFFFFFull))) ? 0x0000000020000000ull : 0ull); //rounding
        fE2 += F2 & 0x7FF0000000000000ull;
        F2 &= 0x000FFFFFE0000000ull;

        *pfData = S2 | ((fE2 | F2) << 3) | ((S1 | ((fE1 | F1) << 3)) >> 32);

        if (i == 88)
            continue;

    }
}

int valTestFtoD(float *inData, double *outData, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if ((((double)inData[i]) != outData[i]) && ((inData[i] == inData[i]) || (outData[i] == outData[i])))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int valTestDtoF(double *inData, float*outData, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if ((((float)inData[i]) != outData[i]) && ((inData[i] == inData[i]) || (outData[i] == outData[i])))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

void testFloatToDouble()
{
    std::cout << "\nSTART Float to Double TEST\n";
    int elemNum = 1024 * 1024 * 8;
    float *f_arr = new float[elemNum];
    double *d_arr = new double[elemNum];

    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    f_arr[0] = 2.0f;
    for (int i = 1; i < elemNum; i++)
    {
        f_arr[i] = i / f_arr[i - 1];
        d_arr[i] = 0.0f;
    }
    long long duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
    std::cout << "init of floats and doubles done in " << duration << std::endl;

    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < elemNum; i++)
    {
        d_arr[i] = f_arr[i];
    }
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
    std::cout << "cast to double done in " << duration << std::endl;

    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    float pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
    float e = 2.71828182845904523536;
    f_arr[0] = pi;
    d_arr[0] = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i < elemNum; i++)
    {
        f_arr[i] = (e + i) / f_arr[i - 1];
        d_arr[i] = 0.0;
    }
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
    std::cout << "init of floats and doubles done in " << duration << std::endl;

    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    toDouble(f_arr, d_arr, elemNum);
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
    std::cout << "toDouble done in " << duration << std::endl;

    std::cout << "toDouble validation test ";
    int errorPos = valTestFtoD(f_arr, d_arr, elemNum);
    if (errorPos < 0)
        std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
    else
    {
        std::cout << "FAIL at " << errorPos << std::endl;
        std::cout << "float [" << errorPos << "]= " << f_arr[errorPos] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "double[" << errorPos << "]= " << d_arr[errorPos] << std::endl;
    }

    delete[] f_arr;
    delete[] d_arr;

    std::cout << "END TEST\n";
}

void testDoubleToFloat()
{
    std::cout << "\nSTART Double to Float TEST\n";
    int elemNum = 1024 *1024 * 8;
    float *f_arr = new float[elemNum];
    double *d_arr = new double[elemNum];

    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    d_arr[0] = 2.0f;
    for (int i = 1; i < elemNum; i++)
    {
        d_arr[i] = i / d_arr[i - 1];
        f_arr[i] = 0.0f;
    }
    long long duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
    std::cout << "init of floats and doubles done in " << duration << std::endl;

    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < elemNum; i++)
    {
        f_arr[i] = (float)d_arr[i];
    }
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
    std::cout << "cast to float done in " << duration << std::endl;

    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
    double e = 2.71828182845904523536;  

    d_arr[0] = pi;      
    f_arr[0] = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 1; i < elemNum; i++)
    {       
        d_arr[i] = (e+i) / d_arr[i - 1];

        f_arr[i] = 0.0f;
    }



    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
    std::cout << "init of floats and doubles done in " << duration << std::endl;

    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    toFloat(d_arr, f_arr, elemNum);
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
    std::cout << "toFloat done in " << duration << std::endl;

    std::cout << "toFloat validation test ";
    int errorPos = valTestDtoF(d_arr, f_arr, elemNum);
    if (errorPos < 0)
        std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
    else
    {
        std::cout << "FAIL at " << errorPos << std::endl;           
        std::cout << "double[" << errorPos << "]= " << d_arr[errorPos] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "float[" << errorPos << "]= " << f_arr[errorPos] << std::endl;
    }

    delete[] f_arr;
    delete[] d_arr;

    std::cout << "END TEST\n";
}

int main()
{
    testFloatToDouble();
    testDoubleToFloat();
}
```

[online example](http://cpp.sh/35jpd)

Comment: That's way too many ALU instructions to be worth doing. (https://godbolt.org/g/1EURvH).  I think even if you manually vectorized it to go from 64 bits to 128 bits (like the packed convert instruction) it wouldn't be worth spending any cycles on using execution resources for this instead of FPU conversion.  `CVTPS2PD xmm, m64` is 2 uops on Haswell (port 0 and a load port), with one-per-clock throughput.  Same for the ymm, m128 version.  So Intel CPUs can already convert as fast as they can store (at one vector result per clock).  (source: http://agner.org/optimize/)

Comment: Mixing this in to a load/convert/store loop would only slow it down, on x86.

Comment: @PeterCordes maybe you are right as it's 2x slower then normal conversion on x64 and as I said it's not a solution it's just a example that you can do it. I also don't have proper skills to optimize it on assembly level but I know that you can parallel floating and integer operations on single core and this is base for me to think that he could use solution like that.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good idea, it just turns out that it's not helpful in practice.  I regret downvoting (maybe make an edit to point out that it's not helpful in practice so I can undo it :P).

Comment: On Intel CPUs, the vector execution units are on the same ports as integer execution units.  Even if that wasn't the case, bottlenecks on total uop throughput are an issue (if data is hot in L1 cache so you don't just bottleneck on memory bandwidth).  It might possibly be a win to mix in one bithack conversion into an unrolled loop of 7 CVTPS2PD vector conversions, but even doing the scalar stores is a problem.  (Intel and AMD CPUs can only do one store per clock, regardless of width, and spending that cycle on a 64b scalar store is worse than spending it on a 256b or 128b vector store).

Comment: If you can come up with anything for double->float, that could be useful, especially for non-AVX, since an SSE vector of doubles only turns into a 64bit pair of floats.  CVTPD2PS is 2 uops for p1 and p5 (on Haswell), for the SSE or 256b AVX version, so it would take an extra shuffle (p5) to combine two vectors into a maximum-width vector to store.

Comment: @PeterCordes Will do double to float tomorrow as is 5 AM in Poland right now ;) but it will have probably same complexity as float to double.

Comment: Right, I'd expect that or worse.  (And it will probably be worse for accuracy since you'll have to truncate the mantissa I guess.)  But the point is that it *might* be useful to mix in one integer-based conversion per 7 vector conversions for the double->float direction or something, because that direction results in only half-width vector stores, or else an extra shuffle per full-width store.  So there's maybe some spare execution resources left over that you could fill by mixing in integer operations.

Comment: @PeterCordes it take me a long time but I finally done it and make it IEEE compatible but make it also a little bit slower.

Comment: Nice.  It's potentially useful to have a reference integer implementation, even if it's slow.

Answer (score 1):

> A data structure is stored as floats, but a third party processing library expects an array of double.

Can it process in cache-size chunks?

If it wasn't stuck in a 3rd-party library, the best thing would be to convert on the fly, loading a pair of doubles from a pair of floats with [`_mm_cvtps_pd`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_cvtps_pd&expand=1679), and similarly storing back to float, so you never have an array of `double` in memory.

But if you can't do that, you can at least feed the data to the library while it's still hot in L1 or L2 cache after reading some floats and writing some doubles.

Actually, if it's a "wire format", then presumably the data has to go through the CPU on the way to memory in the first place, unless you have a zero-copy receive API that DMAs right into your buffer.  The ideal place for conversion might be in small chunks as you receive each packet.  Either copy with conversion directly to `double`, or copy to both `float` and `double` arrays if you also need the original `float` data.

Comment: The library needs a complete array. I don't have the source around, I read and convert on the fly. Still, two for the price of one :)

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: yup, whatever you can do to minimize the number of times your data has to move between cache and RAM.  If your array is huge, it might be worth using NT stores in the conversion loop.  Or maybe while writing both float and double, using NT stores for the one that will be used second?  But if everything fits in L3, don't do that.